# Show argument values instead of variable names in robot framework logs

Tags: robotframework

In the log.html file produced by a [robot framework](http://robotframework.org/) test suite execution we see the executed keywords with their arguments. Something like:

```
${result}= do some calculations  ${arg1}   ${arg2}   ${arg3}
```

Can it be configured to log the actual values of the arguments instead?

```
${result}= do some calculations  33   2014   Bil
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set log level value to TRACE when running the case. You'll then see the argument values in the logs.

```
pybot --loglevel TRACE mytests.txt
```